# Structuring batches with multi label sequence in LSTM rnn tensorflow network

Tags: tensorflow, sequence, dimensions, lstm

Im pretty new to NNs and i m trying to solve the following problem in Python and tensorflow:

I have a sequence of 4 timesteps consisting of 3 Inputs each timestep

start sequence

- 1,1,1
- 2,2,2
- 3,3,3
- 4,4,4

end sequence

- 5,5,5
- 6,6,6
- 7,7,7
- 8,8,8

Then i have Labels containg also 4 timesteps but each has a length of just 2 ouptuts

start sequence

- 1,1
- 2,2
- 3,3
- 4,4

end sequence

- 5,5
- 6,6
- 7,7
- 8,8

In General i want to predict a sequence of multiple outputs from a sequence of multiple Inputs.

- 9,9,9
- 10,10,10
- 11,11,11
- 12,12,12

output:

- ?,?
- ?,?
- ?,?
- ?,?

I ve tried a lot of Tutorials on the net but i end up with shape errors and i know the Problem lies in the provided dimensions for the LSTM cell.It seems like most of them only allow one dimension in the end  I also don't know how to batch this kind of data structure properly in my batch function.

some code snippets:

```
num_samples = 8 #how many data samples to load in tensor
num_inputs = 3
num_labels = 2
timesteps = 4


x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_samples, num_inputs , 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_labels])
```

there is a "1" in the "x" placehholder. It only accepts this structure.
but i would like to have something like:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_samples, batch, num_inputs])
```

my TF specific code snippets:

```
 x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
# Reshaping to (timesteps *batch_size, num_inputs )
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
# Split to get a list of 'timesteps' tensors of shape (batch_size, num_inputs )
x = tf.split(0, timesteps , x)


lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)



outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32,
                            sequence_length=timesteps )


outputs = tf.pack(outputs)
print np.array(outputs)
outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])



# Hack to build the indexing and retrieve the right output.
batch_size = tf.shape(outputs)[0]


# Start indices for each sample
index = tf.range(0, batch_size) * seq_max_len + (seqlen - 1)
# Indexing
outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden]), index)

# Linear activation, using outputs computed above
return tf.matmul(outputs, weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = dynamicRNN(x, seqlen, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)ent

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

Code from the Training part:

```
 while step * batch_size < training_iters:
    batch_x, batch_y, batch_seqlen = trainset.next(batch_size)
    # Run optimization op (backprop)


    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                   seqlen: batch_seqlen})
    if step % display_step == 0:
        # Calculate batch accuracy
        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                            seqlen: batch_seqlen})
        # Calculate batch loss
        loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                         seqlen: batch_seqlen})
        print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
              "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
              "{:.5f}".format(acc))
    step += 1
```

Does anyone have a simple Code snippet for my problem?

Best regards